# A-frame add enable/disable component on function

Tags: javascript, function, three.js, aframe, webvr

I have created a scene using A-frame (https://aframe.io) and I currently have some rain in my scene and a button. What I would like to do is when the button is clicked, a function occurs, I'm wondering how I can make this function remove the `rain` component from the scene. Code:

```
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/v0.4.0/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/takahirox/aframe-rain/master/build/aframe-rain.min.js"></script> 
</head>
 
<body>
<button onclick="toggleRain()">
Toggle rain
</button>
  <a-scene rain>

<a-entity position="0 0 10">
      <a-camera></a-camera>
    </a-entity>
 
    <a-entity geometry="primitive:sphere"></a-entity>
 
    <a-sky color="#222"></a-sky>
 
    <a-entity light="type:directional;color:#666" position="-10 -10 -10"></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

What I would like to happen is when the `toggleRain()` function is triggered, the
`<a-scene rain>` part of the code will change and remove the rain part so there is just

```
<a-scene>
```

This should stop the rain from falling when the button is clicked. Just to clarify, when the function is triggered, it should `rain` property from the   `<a-scene rain>` leaving just

```
<a-scene>
```

How can this be done? Link to fiddle containing code: https://jsfiddle.net/AidanYoung/z7qstgua/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `removeAttribute()` to remove the `rain`

```js
function toggleRain() {
  let a = document.getElementById('a');
  if (a.hasAttribute('rain')) {
    a.removeAttribute('rain');
  } else {
    a.setAttribute('rain', '1');
  }
  console.log ("ok");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/v0.4.0/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/takahirox/aframe-rain/master/build/aframe-rain.min.js"></script> 
</head>
 
<body>
<button onclick="toggleRain()">
Toggle rain
</button>
  <a-scene  id="a" rain>

<a-entity position="0 0 10">
      <a-camera></a-camera>
    </a-entity>
 
    <a-entity geometry="primitive:sphere"></a-entity>
 
    <a-sky color="#222"></a-sky>
 
    <a-entity light="type:directional;color:#666" position="-10 -10 -10"></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: Could also use `hasAttribute()` instead of `getAttribute()`. (I know, I know, a petty nit.)